# Airline Overbooking - the minimum number of seats to be booked on the aircraft for a given probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Here's the problem:

Air travel is often overbooked by tour operators, because a booked trip will not be taken with a probability of 10%. In this task we assume that the decisions of the individual bookers to take the trip or not are independent of each other.

a) A tour operator books 56 flights with an airline and sells 60 flights to his customers. What is the probability that the seats are sufficient?

b) A tour operator wants to sell 60 seats to his customers. How many seats in the aircraft does he have to book so that there is at least a 95% probability that they will be enough?

c) An organizer books 43 seats on an airline. How many seats can he sell to his customers so that there is a probability of at least 95% that the seats are enough?

My thoughts:

a)  $$p(x \leq 4)= p(x = 0) + p(x = 1) + p(x = 2) + p(x = 3) + p(x = 4) \\
           = \sum\limits_{x=0}^{4} \binom{n}{k} {0.9}^{n-k}{0.1}^{k} \\
           =0.271
$$

b)

We are looking for a k for which applies:

$$1-p(x \leq k) \geq 0.95 \Rightarrow 1-p(x \leq k) \geq 0.05 $$

$$\Rightarrow  \\
p(x=0) = 0.0018     \\
p(x \le1 1) = 0.0138    \\
p(x <= 2) = 0,053    \\
 \Rightarrow 
$$
the organiser must book at least 59 places, so that there is at least a 95% probability that the places will be sufficient.

c)
The probability that a passenger will appear is 0.9.
In order for at least 43 passengers to appear with a probability of at least 0.95, the probability of 0 to 42 passengers coming must fall to a maximum of 0.05.

So we have k=42 and p=0.9 (because in the cumulative distribution the sum of 0 to 42 is then calculated) and experiment with n until it fits.

$\binom{n}{42} 0.9^n 0.1^{n - 42} \leq 0.05$

---

However, I am confronted with the problem of making sure whether the solution for a) and b) is correct or not and I am not sure how to solve the subtask c).Can someone please explain it to me?

I would also appreciate other calculation possibilities.
Thanks so much :)

Comment: for a), you found probability that four or less people will not make the trip. But you need at least four people not to make the trip to have sufficient seating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a) there are not enough seats if three or less people could not make the trip $$p(x \leq 3)= p(x = 0) + p(x = 1) + p(x = 2) + p(x = 3) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{3} \binom{n}{k} {0.9}^{n-k}{0.1}^{k} \approx 0.1374$$ Thus, the probability to have enough seats is $1-p(x \leq 3)=0.8626$

For b) your reasoning and result look good to me.

For c), look at the result from b). To achieve at least $95\%$ probability, the difference between bookings and seats cannot be greater than $1$ (considering also that we have fewer seats in our case). Thus, the organizer cannot sell more than $44$ tickets. However, $1-p(x \le 1) \approx 0.943$ which is less than required $95\%$. This tell us that the only way to guarantee sufficient seats is to sell exactly $43$ tickets (or less).